# bootstrap datepicker locale/language doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datepicker

JS and css Added-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="foto/logo.png" />
<link href='css/hover.css' rel='stylesheet' media='all'>

<script src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/script.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.id.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
```

Javascript Code-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="datepicker"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  var options={
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true, 
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0",
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0",
    language: "id",
    locale: "id",
  };
  date_input.datepicker({options});
})
</script>
```

HTML-

```
<input class="form-control" id="date" name="datepicker" placeholder=" -- (tahun/bulan/tanggal) -- " type="text"/>
```

bootstrap datepicker locale/languange doesn't work
am I missing something?
bootstrap datepicker locale/languange doesn't work
am I missing something?
bootstrap datepicker locale/languange doesn't work
am I missing something?
bootstrap datepicker locale/languange doesn't work
am I missing something?

Comment: try date_input.datepicker(options);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.min.css`, And also there is syntax error in following line:

```
date_input.datepicker({options});
```

It should be:

```
date_input.datepicker(options);
```

Try following working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var date_input=$('input[name="datepicker"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  var options={
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true, 
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0",
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0",
    language: "id",
    locale: "id",
  };
  date_input.datepicker(options);  
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.id.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<input class="form-control" id="date" name="datepicker" placeholder=" -- (tahun/bulan/tanggal) -- " type="text"/>
```

Comment: I'm not missing jquery.js nor bootstrap.min.css, I just forgot to put it in the question box hehe
but the problem is in the date_input.datepicker({options});
thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the Jquery on top of that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

and then followed by your js and css

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.id.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try find the appropriate your timezone
[here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/)

add this for example

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/locale/id.js"></script>
```